# Extend saveShippingInformation js in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am building a module for Magento 2. I extend the saveShippingInformation in Magento 2 to add my custom field

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'My_Module/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'
        }
    }
};
```

// Custom shipping-save-processor, I added the new extension_attributes to addressInformation

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address'
    ],
    function (
        $,
        ko,
        quote,
        resourceUrlManager,
        storage,
        paymentService,
        methodConverter,
        errorProcessor,
        fullScreenLoader,
        selectBillingAddressAction
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            saveShippingInformation: function () {
                var payload;

                if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
                    selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
                }

                payload = {
                    addressInformation: {
                        shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                        billing_address: quote.billingAddress(),
                        shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                        shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                        extension_attributes:{
                            fee: $('[name="fee"]').prop("checked")
                        }
                    }
                };

                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

                return storage.post(
                    resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
                    JSON.stringify(payload)
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                        paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response.payment_methods));
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        errorProcessor.process(response);
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }
```

My question is: Is this a bad practice to override the magento js like this? What if the merchant's theme overrides this js, it's gonna override my js too, right? In that case, how can I add custom field to addressInformation module

Comment: Use mixin instead of overwriting this class

Comment: Great idea! I will take a look at how to use mixin